# Can one-to-one bidirectional releationship cause OutOfMemory Error?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate 5

I don't understand how Hibernate manages things well and my question might seem quite dumb. Consider the following simepl one-to-one bidirectional relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "player", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private PlayerPoints points;

    //other columns GET, SET
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "player_points")
public class PlayerPoints {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Player.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    private Player player;

    //Other columns, get set
}
```

So, what if we query the following collection of `Player`s through criteria API:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
//...
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().creaetCriteria(Player.class);
List<Player> players = criteria.list();
```

Since any `Player` of the List `players` maintains a reference to a `PlayerPoints` and each `PlayerPoints` maintain a reference to `Player` I'd guess that they're never destroyed by GC (reference counting will never goes to zero).

I think it may cause `OutOfMemoryError`.

So, why is one-to-one bidirectional relationship actually safe?

Comment: Can you share what exact SQL question Hibernate generates under the hood? (with setting "hibernate.show_sql" to `true` in your Hibernate configuration)

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun Well, I don't see why the SQL-query may be important here...

Comment: Because you don't really 100% sure what SQL query is executed and sometimes Hibernate do really strange things internally. And how it's implemented internally is your main source of _possible_ problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Hibernate. If you have two object instances and they reference each other, but none of them is reachable from the other objects in the application, garbage collector is smart enough to eliminate both of them.

When `Session` is closed (or cleared), Hibernate will not reference entity instances any more (they become detached) and they will be garbage collected if the rest of your application code doesn't reference them either.